# Sometimes the template returns null

Tags: powershell, ssom

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://SPWeb/sites/MyApps/Orders"
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Order_Template"}
$newweb = New-SPWeb -Url "http://SPWeb/sites/MyApps/Orders/x2" -Name "X2"
$newweb.ApplyWebTemplate($template.name)
```

Sometimes ApplyWebTemplate gives error saying template is null. 
Sometimes it works.

If I hardcode the id it always work:

```
$newweb.ApplyWebTemplate("{2259B9C7-884F-41F5-8A77-95880CEE31FB}#Order_Template")
```

I know it crazy but it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent automatic garbage collection using `Start-SPAssignment` as follows:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://SPWeb/sites/MyApps/Orders"
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Order_Template"}
$newweb = New-SPWeb -Url "http://SPWeb/sites/MyApps/Orders/x2" -Name "X2"
$newweb.ApplyWebTemplate($template.name)
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

For details, see [Start-SPAssignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/start-spassignment?view=sharepoint-ps) on Microsoft docs.

Also, see this related question: [Object returned by Get-SPSiteAdministration cmdlet has no valid values](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243066/object-returned-by-get-spsiteadministration-cmdlet-has-no-valid-values/243067#243067)

What you can also try is using the "-Template" argument of `New-SPWeb`:

```
$newweb = New-SPWeb -Url "http://SPWeb/sites/MyApps/Orders/x2" -Name "X2" -Template $template.Name
```

You will *not* have to use `SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate()`

Comment: I did the changes you suggested but still the same result.

Comment: @ShashiB Ok... try the -Template argument instead or in combination with the Start-SPAssignment approach.